# Compact sets are bounded: shape of the cover matters?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

To prove a compact sets is bounded, we assume there's a "open ball cover" (each with R=1) that covers the set. And take maximum distance over the center of the balls +2 as the boundary. Why could we assume this without actually knowing the "shape" of the cover? How do we know if such "open ball cover" is able to cover the set presumably? Maybe such "ball-shaped" cover is not able to cover the set.

Answer (score 1):

The usual strategy is to let the open cover of the compact set $K$ be $\mathcal B=\{B(x,1):x\in K\}$. Since each point in $K$ has its own ball, $\mathcal B$ definitely covers $K$. Since $K$ is compact, there exists a finite subcover.

Comment: "Definitely" is topologically correct?

Comment: Sorry, I was speaking informally, What I mean is that since each element of $K$ has a ball assigned to it specifically, there can be no doubt that $\mathcal B$ covers $K$.

Comment: But can you make sure you can assign R=1 to each of the balls?

Comment: you can take the intersection of the balls of radius 1 with the sets of your original open cover,  the intersection of two open sets is open and you'll still have bounded

Comment: or just start with the balls of radius 1,  since for compactness, ANY open cover must have a finite subcover

Comment: So there might be "something" in the open ball but not in the space that we've been discussing? (That are neglected when taking the intersection) This sounds a bit unusual.

Comment: The intersection is not necessary. For each $x\in K$, just put a ball in you open cover centered at $x$ with radius 1. This is an open cover of $K$ because every point has it's own ball of radius 1. Because $K$ is compact, there exists a finite subcover.

Answer (score 0):

The function $d(x,y)$, defined on $K \times K \rightarrow \mathbb R$ , is a continuous (uniformly-continuous, actually) Real-valued function, defined on the compact set $K\times K$. A continuous function on a compact set reaches , takes on a (finite) maximum value, say $M$. This value can serve as the diameter of a ball containing $K$.

And re the issue of covering, by definition of a cover $S$, any element  $x$ in $K$ is in a set $S_k$ of the cover. Then $\cup$ $S_k${$x \in K, s\in S$} contains every element of $K$.